# Autowired in Spring giving an error : Injection of autowired dependencies failed

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I'm getting this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'newStep2Controller': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void projecthealth.web.NewStep2Controller.setUserService(projecthealth.service.UserService); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [projecthealth.service.UserService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1120)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
```

Controller class

```
  @Controller
  @RequestMapping("/newStep2.htm")
  @SessionAttributes("user")
  @ComponentScan("projecthealth.service")
 public class NewStep2Controller
 {
 protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());
 private UserService userService;

@Autowired
public void setUserService(UserService userService) {
    this.userService = userService;
}
   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showUserForm(ModelMap model)
{
    model.addAttribute("user");

    return "userForm";
}
```

service is existing:

```
  public interface UserService {

void createUser(User user)  throws ServiceException;

/**
 * 
 * @param userId (email is user id)
 * @return
 * @throws ServiceException
 */
User getUserById(String userId)  throws ServiceException;

void deleteUser(String userId)  throws ServiceException;

/**
 * 
 * @param newUserObject
 * @param userId (email is user id)
 * @return
 * @throws ServiceException
 */
User updateUser(User newUserObject, String userId)  throws ServiceException;
 }
```

I've added this to the xml

```
 <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
```

I've added the UserServiceImpl

```
    public class UserServiceImpl extends BaseServiceImpl<User> implements UserService{

public static final String FIELD_EMAIL = "email";

public void createUser(User user) throws ServiceException {
    insert(user);
}

public User getUserById(String userId) throws ServiceException {
    return (User) findOne(User.class, FIELD_EMAIL, userId);
}

public void deleteUser(String userId) throws ServiceException {
    delete(User.class, FIELD_EMAIL, userId);
}

public User updateUser(User newUserObject, String oldEmail) throws ServiceException {
    MongoTemplate template = getTemplate();
    User userObject = getUserById(oldEmail);

    List<DietCategory> dietaryPreferences = newUserObject.getDietaryPreferences();

    if(dietaryPreferences != null){
        userObject.setDietaryPreferences(dietaryPreferences);
    }
    userObject.setEmail(newUserObject.getEmail());
    userObject.setFirstname(newUserObject.getFirstname());
    userObject.setHeight(newUserObject.getHeight());
    userObject.setLastname(newUserObject.getLastname());
    userObject.setPassword(newUserObject.getPassword());
    userObject.setWeight(newUserObject.getWeight());
    template.save(userObject);
    return newUserObject;
}

public List<User> getAllUser() throws ServiceException {
    return findAll(User.class);
}
```

stackoverflow is making add more text because there is too much code in my post. 
you could ignore this comment.

Comment: And where is the implementation of your interface? Spring must instantiate something, and it can't be interface.

Answer (score 2):

It would be better if you provided an implementation of UserService.

Make sure the implementation is annotated with @Service.

Comment: so above where i have the UserSerivceImpl, i should include @Service above the line "public class UserServiceImpl extends BaseServiceImpl" ??

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a bean UserService in your xml.

Or your controller can't find it !

Answer (score 0):

What about implementation of your Service? Did you annotated your UserService class  and UserService's implementation class with @Service annotation?
You can also skip getter&setter in Controller and set @Autowired annotation to your field, I know that it works, but I have no idea how.

You have also to instruct Spring to search for those annotations in specified packages, this is how I do:

```
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="your_package"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The @ComponentScan will only work on a javaConfig. Either you use the Javaconfig or the xml configuration but anyways you will need to manage your service as a spring bean !

Source : http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html